# Can I specify HTML data attributes as true/false or must they be strings?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<li>
    <a class="button accessLink"
    data-disabled="no"
    data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Logout"
    title="Logout"><span class="smaller">LOGOUT</span></a>
</li>
```

I specified data-disabled as "no" but is it possible to use the values true / false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, in HTML5, unless you use XHTML serialization (in which case normal XML rules apply).

In HTML serialization of HTML5, the [attribute syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) allows the use of the attribute name alone, in which case the implied value is the empty string. When using `data-` attributes in scripting (or styling), you can then use constructs that test for the presence of the attribute.

You can check out that http://validator.nu/ accepts an element like `<a data-disabled>foo</a>`.

Answer (score 5):

No, HTML5 data-* attributes' values are strings.

You can of course use the strings `"true"` and `"false"`.